# How to render data related specifically to a user when they login?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm working on a small application and I'm relatively new to programming. I've been using MEAN stack to start and have run into a snag.  I have this code here that will render a name when a page is loaded.

```
<tr ng-repeat = "contact in users">
    <td>{{contact.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

In my controller I have this code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  console.log("Hello World from controller");

  var refresh = function() {
    $http.get('/users').success(function(response) {
      console.log("I got the data I requested");
      $scope.users = response;
      $scope.contact = "";
    });
  };

  refresh();
```

And then in my server I have this

```
app.get('/users', function (req, res) {
  console.log('I received a GET request');

  db.users.find( {_id: mongojs.ObjectId("55563359e430458542c0f36f")},       function (err, docs) {

    console.log(docs);
    res.json(docs);
  });
});
```

This works great when I want to render that user. However this only allows me to render one of my users names. And it's whichever one I hard code into the `db.user.find`. What I would like to do is figure out a way to render a user's name based of off some specific session/variable when they login.  So essentially when a user logs in have the values specific to their credentials display I used this tutorial https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local for a beginners authentication. I figured I would be able to take the session and then somehow pass it down to my get statement on the server but so far I haven't been able to figure it out. Any suggestion would be great even if it means me scrapping what I have.

Comment: `var o={}; o._id=mongojs.ObjectId("5...6f"); db.users.find( o, ...`

Comment: there are a lot of ways to do this.. one easy way would be to add the user as an attribute to the session obj (e.g. `req.session.regenerate(function () { req.session.user = username; });` and use it in your `/users` route, e.g. `db.users.find( {user: req.session.user )}`